# fglrx causing "fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed" on Intel/AMD hybrid graphics

Tags: linux-mint, laptop, amd-graphics, hybrid-graphics

I am currently using Linux Mint 17.2 Cinnamon 64-bit on my laptop with hybrid graphics (Intel/AMD) and I can't get the AMD proprietary graphics drivers (fglrx) running properly. They always put my system in an unusable state. I also tried other distributions (Ubuntu 14.04, Ubuntu 15.04, openSuse, CentOS, ElementaryOS) and get similar errors.

The problem is: On a fresh install, i do all system updates. Then I install fglrx via the drivers tool that comes preinstalled. I select fglrx, apply the changes and reboot. When the system boots up, I can see the plymouth splash, then a black screen that shows "login" for a short period (I guess thats where the auto login happens). After that a whole bunch of text comes up and it says "fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed". At that moment I press CTRL+ALT+DEL and the system reboots and shows me "fixing recursive fault but reboot is needed" again. I repeated that process a couple of times and finaly the desktop showed up. I do "amdconfig --initial" and reboot. Again the recursive faults... but this time I gave up after >10 reboots not working.

What am I doing wrong? Do I have to install some additional packages/dependencies? Has anyone experienced similar behavior?
Any help is appreciated. Btw it worked perfectly fine on MS Windows, so the hardware doesn't seem to be broken.

Specs

- Lenovo G510 laptop
- Intel Core i7-4700MQ
- Intel HD Graphics 4600
- AMD Radeon HD 8750M

uname -r

```
3.16.0-38-generic
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Mars [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8750M] (rev ff)
08:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA8172 Fast Ethernet (rev 10)
```

Comment: You have a hybrid AMD Graphics System.  The `Intel HD Graphics 4600` Computes and Renders. The `AMD Radeon HD 8750M` only renders, therefore you must use the Intel Based Card to compute, and then send the output to the AMD Based Card.  See [HybridGraphics](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics), and this [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/522177/intel-amd-hybrid-graphics-on-ubuntu-14-04) post.

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. Of course I have hybrid graphics and I know how they work. Sorry if it wasn't clear enough in my post, I'll edit it. The first link you sent me suggests to install fglrx, nothing else. That's what I'm having problems with. I don't know what to make of the second link. Should I try the "nomodeset"? I dont want to wreck my system again...

Answer (score 1):

### Problem

Hybrid Graphics Systems require two graphics drivers.  Your issue is that you are trying to use only one driver to "drive" two totally different cards.  On the Kernel Level this is done with the `vga-switcharoo` [kernel setting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics), which is enabled on major distributions by default.  The issue is further compounded by the fact that the switcharoo option isn't smart, ie. the kernel knows what the cards are attempting to do, but with improperly configured userspace tools, the kernel can't decode the proper option

### Solution - Part 1

In order to get to a properly working Desktop, I'm assuming that nothing  works properly.  In order to fix this, readers can:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F3</kbd>.  This should display a Text-Mode TTY.
2. Login using your credentials.
3. Assuming your using Cinnamon, with default settings, issue a `sudo service mdm stop` to temporarily disable the Cinnamon Desktop.
4. Test for Internet Connectivity by issuing `sudo ping -c4 www.mint.org`.
5. Uninstall all FRGLX drivers, by issuing `sudo apt-get purge frglx*`
6. Remove the XOrg.conf File: `sudo rm -v /etc/X11/xorg.conf`
7. Reinstall the Intel XOrg Driver: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel`
8. Reinstall XOrg: `sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64`
9. Reconfigure XOrg: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg`
10. Restart the XOrg Server: `sudo service mdm start`

---

### Solution - Part 2

*Method 1 - The Mint Way*: Try this First.  In your now running desktop, click the Mint Menu.  In the Search Box, type <kbd>D</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>.  An Entry for Driver Manager should appear.  Select it, and let it scan the system for 3rd party hardware.  In the list will be the version of `frglx` in the Mint Repositories.  This **does not install Control Center**.  See **Final Steps**.

Use the [Answers outlined here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522177/intel-amd-hybrid-graphics-on-ubuntu-14-04), involving `amdconfig` to properly switch cards, until you complete **Final Steps**.

*Method 2 - Directly from AMD*: This should be a last resort, therefore use with caution.  I say this because these packages may not be the versions in the official Mint repositories.  Visit the [AMD Catalyst™ Driver for Linux Download Page](http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Ubuntu%20x86%2064).  Download:

- AMD Catalyst™ 15.7 Proprietary Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 Video Driver for Graphics Accelerators
- AMD Catalyst™ 15.7 Proprietary Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 Catalyst Control Center

Don't be alarmed that the Downloads say Ubuntu, as Mint is a fork of Ubuntu LTS.  Issue a `sudo dpkg -i fglrx*` from a terminal in the directory where the downloads are saved.  If warned to use the `--force` option, **don't**, or you may end up having to restart at Part 1.

---

### Final Steps

After completing either method, install `fglrx-pxpress` with `sudo apt-get install fglrx-pxpress` and reboot.  After reboot issue `inxi -G`, which should report your ATI Card is now active.  If you used method one, you should now install Catalyst Control Center. Issue `sudo apt-get install fglrx-amdcccle`.  Doing so ensures that the driver you installed in the driver Manager matches the Control Center Version.

Reboot once more, and upon returning to desktop, issue `sudo amdcccle` to Start Control Center.  Choose Integrated from the Graphics Card Settings, and test.

---

### Caveats

1. You cannot use the Catalyst Control Center to "switch cards," as using full Intel disables the RadeonHD, and using full RadeonHD disables the Intel HD, which will crash the XOrg server.  When updating, you must use the Driver Manager to update the `frglx` driver, because Integrated must be used at all times. Installing the `frglx` drivers from the command line assumes that the ATI Card is the only GPU on the system. See the answer I linked above, specifically item 4.
2. In order for XOrg to behave properly, it must always be started with the Intel Based Driver.  This will be done automatically, once the Control Center is set to Integrated.
3. After being properly setup, readers can choose card usage based on the application, i.e. if you're using a game you tell the Control Center in its per Application Setting to turn on the Discrete Card only.  In this way, all computations are done by the IntelHD Card and then the result is offloaded to the RadeonHD Card for rendering.

---

### References

[Ask Ubuntu - Intel/AMD Hybrid graphics on Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/522177/intel-amd-hybrid-graphics-on-ubuntu-14-04)
[How to Stop the Graphical User Interface on Ubuntu and Linux Mint](http://linuxg.net/how-to-stop-the-graphical-user-interface-on-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/)
[How to Properly Remove the Proprietary ATI Drivers on Debian, Ubuntu and Linux Mint](http://linuxg.net/how-to-properly-remove-the-proprietary-ati-drivers-on-debian-ubuntu-and-linux-mint/)
[How do I install a .deb file via the command line?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/40779/how-do-i-install-a-deb-file-via-the-command-line)
[Mint Forums - Installing AMD/Intel Hybrid Graphic System Drivers in Mint 16](http://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/1501)

Comment: Thank you! That's a very thorough answer. I have a few qustions though: vga-switcharoo seems to be only for muxed graphics. My hardware is muxless as far as I know. I installed fglrx via driver manager and it installes the ccc automatically. fglrx-pxpress is not required according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/HybridGraphics

Comment: `vga-switcharoo` is used in both cases.  Turning on the Discrete Card/Off the integrated and vice versa is done via the `vga-switcharoo` option because the only difference between muxed, and muxless is the power saving option.  See [this Redit Post](http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/vosq5/muxless_graphics_optimuscrossdisplay_must_die/) from some haters, and [this WikiPedia Entry on ATI Support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AMD_Hybrid_Graphics)

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with AMD Intel and Linux Mint 17.3. I updated my kernel to 4.x and now I am using xserver-xorg-video-ati (recommended, open source) with no such problems.
`fglrx` was giving problems for me: I was not able to use hardware acceleration in chrome.
So, updating kernel might be a solution worth trying