# Radeon graphics with Linux Mint 18

Tags: linux-mint, drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I have a Lenovo g40 that came with Windows 10. It came with a AMD Radeon R5 M230with 2GB dedicated memory.

I just installed Linux Mint 18.1 on it and it installed with no errors, but I can't see the graphics card listed and so I don't think it's in use.

The only time I can see the graphics card listed is by issuing `inxi -Fxz`, but I guess that doesn't mean it's in use. Here's part of the output:

```
System:    Host: Lenovo-G40 Kernel: 4.4.0-53-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
           Desktop: MATE 1.16.1 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1)
           Distro: Linux Mint 18.1 Serena
Machine:   System: LENOVO (portable) product: 80JE v: Lenovo G40-80
           Mobo: LENOVO model: Lancer 4A1 v: SDK0J40679 WIN
           Bios: LENOVO v: B0CN93WW date: 07/23/2015
CPU:       Dual core Intel Core i5-5200U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 3072 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 8778
           clock speeds: max: 2700 MHz 1: 2200 MHz 2: 2200 MHz 3: 2200 MHz
           4: 2200 MHz
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Card-2: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]
           bus-ID: 04:00.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: ati,radeon,intel (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1366x768@59.97hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6 Direct Rendering: Yes
```

So I know the graphics card is there. However I can't see in in `lspci` or `lshw`, which is what matters I think.

Here's the output of `lspci|grep VGA`

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics (rev 09)
```

And here's the output of `lshw -C video`

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Broadwell-U Integrated Graphics
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:49 memory:d0000000-d0ffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

I installed the `intel-microcode` on the driver manager. The version is `3.20151106.1`.

So, I have to say, I am a little bit confused though, since in the Mint 18 release notes it says:

> If you are using an ATI GPU in Linux Mint 18, the operating system
>   will either select the Radeon or AMDGPU drivers for you, and these are
>   installed by default.

So shouldn't the drivers have been installed by default?

Anyway, how can I make this work? (I'm trying to avoid downgrading to 17.3 if possible because of UEFI-related issues).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of the suggestions worked. I read a lot about it and apparently there's just no way. So the answer for this question is: you can't have the Radeon R5 M230 in Mint 18.1 because the support for this version of Ubuntu is dropped (unless maybe you do something really invasive to your system).

The only solution I found to make it work was downgrading to Linux Mint 17.3 and following [this awesome answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/216830/121808)

**EDIT**

Since this question has been viewed a lot I think it deserves an edit at this point.

Since I asked the question some development has been made for AMD support in linux. A few weeks ago I installed Mint 18.2 in a computer with a dual Intel/Radeon R5 graphics with the most up-to-date kernel, which at the time was 4.12.

It wasn't my computer so I didn't have the chance to test it properly, but it appears that the system recognized the Radeon card right after the kernel update (I didn't do anything card-related). So I'm guessing as of now the chances of it working are much better.

Answer (score 2):

Lenovo laptops have a dual graphic card, a radeon and an intel one. On battery, they switch to the intel on its low power consumption.

The radeon linux driver is a proprietary, binaryonly software and it is far in quality from the amd cpus. Furthermore, this switch and this dualcard support isn't very well developed in them. But it works.

The radeon driver, being a third party source, has to be enabled in your package manager. Search for synaptic in your start menu, and enable it, then run a system update.

Comment: That makes sense. I installed Mint with third party software enabled though, so I guess it should be there. I do have two questions. What do I check in synaptic to be sure it's enabled? If I type `radeon` in synaptic, a bunch of things appear (like I said, I'm a newbie when it comes to hardware). And how can I really tell which graphics card is in use?

Comment: In case it's important: the only one of those options for `radeon` in synaptic that's installed in `xserver-xorg-video-radeon`. And I checked the outputs of the commands I listed in my question with the laptop connected to the power and the outputs are still the same.

Answer (score 1):

In reply to *xralf*'s bounty message:
Your card is listed as `Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230]` which means it's  [part of the *"Solar System"* family](https://www.techpowerup.com/178312/amd-sea-islands-and-solar-system-gpu-families-codenames-detailed) and based on `GCN2` architecture:

> Sun: Mainstream part based on second-generation GCN

I recommend the following:

1. Double check your AMD GPU is correctly detected by the OS. Running `lspci | grep VGA` is the wrong way to do it since the pci device class 03 (Display controller) has several [device subclasses with different names](https://admin.pci-ids.ucw.cz/read/PD/03). So either run `lspci | grep -E '(VGA|3D|Display)'` or simply run `lspci` and inspect the output. You should have a line like this:

   ```
   03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c6)
   ```

   Note that `03:00.0` is the `BDF` (`bus:device.function`) which identifies your device.
2. Determine which driver is used by the OS for your GPU. You can do that with `lspci -k -s BDF` e.g. on my setup `lspci -k -s 03:00.0` prints

   ```
   03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev c6)
           Subsystem: Tongfang Hongkong Limited Renoir
           Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
           Kernel modules: amdgpu
   ```

   In my case the driver used is `amdgpu` but in your case, at least based on your `lshw` output, the driver used is `radeon`. So the output in your case might be:

   ```
           Kernel driver in use: radeon
           Kernel modules: radeon, amdgpu
   ```
3. Instruct the kernel to use the `amdgpu` driver instead of `radeon`. Add the following parameters to your kernel boot line:

   ```
   radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.modeset=1
   ```

   the last one (the `modeset`) might not be needed, you can experiment and see if it works without it. From what I gather e.g. [(1)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/927601/i-think-im-using-radeon-instead-of-amdgpu-how-do-i-change), [(2)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1462458/how-can-i-enable-amdgpu-kernel-driver-ubuntu-22-04), [(3)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1266616/how-can-i-use-amdgpu-instead-of-radeon-drivers-on-20-04) that's all that's needed on Ubuntu.
   If you want to try that driver without changing your current configuration follow the guide here: [Temporarily Add a Kernel Boot Parameter for Testing](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/KernelBootParameters#Temporarily_Add_a_Kernel_Boot_Parameter_for_Testing) and add those parameters so you end up with something like:

   ```
   ... quiet splash radeon.cik_support=0 amdgpu.cik_support=1 amdgpu.modeset=1
   ```

   The OS would then boot using the `amdgpu` driver until you reboot the system.

For the record, ArchWiki has a [detailed guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/AMDGPU#Enable_Southern_Islands_(SI)_and_Sea_Islands_(CIK)_support) on enabling `amdgpu` for cards based on GCN/GCN2 architecture (though some of the instructions there are Arch-specific).

Comment: Thank you. To step 3) `amdgpu` is better than `radeon`? Which file should I edit? Isn't enough to put `export DRI_PRIME=1` to my `~/.profile`?

Comment: @xralf - `DRI_PRIME` is to tell the OS which gpu to use (i.e. amd or intel) not which driver. As to the drivers... `radeon` is for the older cards and `amdgpu` for newer cards... yours is in-between. Phoronix has a good [article](https://www.phoronix.com/review/amdgpu-radeon-415) about this and some benchmarks. As you can see there's no big difference,  a 10-15% difference in most cases. Your card is on the low end of the spectrum so I don't think you will notice a big improvement. However, you can always try it _without modifying any file_, via `grub` edit, see my post edit (last paragraph)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that you have 2 graphics cards in your computer one Intel and Radeon. If you like you can use the intel drivers that works fine.
https://01.org/linuxgraphics

I think the installation of this driver is going to configure all X11 stuff.

Comment: The things is that the Intel graphics are integrated in the motherboard, so not very good. The Radeon card is dedicated, so I'd like it to be the one used. How do I use that one?

Comment: I have the same problem. please suggest how can i enable radeon card for my linux mint 18.